# How to move spacemacs neotree window position to the right?

Tags: spacemacs

I'm transitioning from emacs to spacemacs. In emacs I use [neotree](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NeoTree) to have a nice sidebar where I can explore my files. I like it on the right side, so inside my `custom-set-variables` within my init file is:

```
'(neo-window-position (quote right))
```

which works perfectly.

BUT, with spacemacs things are different. I wrote that line inside my `dotspacemacs/user-config()` and nothing happens, when I hit `SPC f t` neotree still appears on the left side.

Can you help me to get it shown on the right? It's almost the only thing I need to feel comfortable working with spacemacs.

Thank you so much. :)

Comment: could it be `neo-tree-mode` might be loaded after your `custom-set-variables` command has executed ?? Check your init file and confirm once

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan there is no custom-set-variables on spacemacs that I know of. Is it? Where?

Comment: If there is no `custom-set-variables` why not add do something like this :- `(eval-after-load  "neotree" '(neo-window-position (quote right)))`.



If even this does not work, maybe you should try `use-package`. It has an option to specify commands to load **after** a package has been loaded (which is what you need to do)

Comment: Also just to confirm your code works, disable `neotree-mode`, go to your `*scratch*` buffer and copy paste `'(neo-window-position (quote right))` and execute the command with `C-M-x` and reload `neotree-mode`. It should pop up on the right after you do this. 

PS. I haven't use `neotree` or spacemacs. but i assume this is how it should work

Comment: Putting `(setq neo-window-position 'right)` in `dotspacemacs/user-config` works for me, so I don't know why it doesn't work for you. By the way, the expression `'(neo-window-position (quote right))` doesn't do anything if it's not inside of `custom-set-variables`.

Answer (score -1):

put 
`neo-window-position 'right`
in the dotspacemacs/init configuration

Comment: can you expand how different this is from the normal emacs configuration mentioned in the question, please?

Comment: Can you add more information to your answer? Relevant docstrings and more elaborate answer would flesh out your question considerably.